# The number of solutions to $a+b=1$ in a multiplicative subgroup of a finite field $GF(q)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields, abelian-groups, cyclotomic-fields, additive-combinatorics

I have been wondering what is the number of solutions to $a+b=1$ in an arbitrary multiplicative subgroup $H$ (order $r$) of some finite field $GF(q)$, where $q=p^n$ is a prime power and $a, b \in H$. If there is no known results for a general $q$, what about the case $q$ is power of $2$?
I'm trying to find a general upper bound on the number of solutions, depending on $p,n$ and $r$.

Comment: are a,b elements of GF(q)?

Comment: No, they are elements of H.

Comment: This feels like a natural question. What was the problem that lead you to ask it? In general it may be difficult to say much, but the worst case upper bound of $r-1$ (when you are free to choose $a$ to be any non-identity element of $H$) is attained at least in the case where $r=p^m-1$, $m\mid n$. The cases where $r$ is much smaller than $q$ feel more interesting (when selecting $q$ to be as small as possible so that the field contains $H$). Need to think about it...

Comment: I'm thinking of an algorithm which in the last step I want to distinguish the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ of $\mathbb{F}_q$ from its subgroups based on the fact that the elements in $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ is almost equal to that in $\mathbb{F}_q^\times+1$. Except for the case $r=p^m-1$, is it true that the number of solutions $N$ is much smaller than $r$? Here much smaller means $1-N/r>1/n$.